# Moving singleton definition into mixins in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mixins

I have to change around 10 classes into singletons and I thought that instead of copy-pasting the code it makes sense to use mixins, like it is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb625996.aspx

However, I need not that much of additional methods, but more additional changes to the class itself, I have problems applying those instructions.

I tried to create an empty interface ISingleton and then to add the singleton part as extension to the new class public static class Singleton

This is singleton part which I would like to use:

```
    public static SomeClass Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new SomeClass ()); }
    }

    private static SomeClass _instance;
```

But when adding it as extension I had a problem - how to define the Instance property, so it will be reusable by many classes? 
And the second issue - I still need to change the constructors to private manually.

Does this approach makes any sense? 
I haven't used mixins before, maybe this is just not the right scenario for it?

Comment: That singleton code isn't thread-safe. Are you really sure you want to do that? Note that singletons really don't mix with inheritance...

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the quick comment! Already reading your article about implementing singletons.

Comment: I think it is depending of the your classes; Do they have all the same behaviour? Can you post some of your classes just to get better feeling for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixins link you gave shows extension methods being used to add functionality to all objects supporting an interface. You still need to create the objects first. As singleton patterns handle the creation of objects it's basicly too soon to apply these techiniques.

Singleton needn't be so complicated, you're reading Jon Skeets article, a simple:

```
public sealed MyClass
{
   private MyClass(){}
   public static MyClass Instance = new MyClass();
}
```

Is often all you need. I'd happily repeat that code 10 times if needed. Or one can use a service locator or IoC container to manage the lifetime of objects.